# Merging parameters rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, merge, strong-parameters

in my rails app, a user can select other users they'd like to join a 'party' with. I'm trying to merge the current user's ID with those that the user has selected. This is one way i've tried:

```
def party_params
   params.require(:party).permit(:length, :game_id, user_ids: []).merge("user_ids" => ["user_ids"] + [current_user.id])
end
```

This comes back with :

> Couldn't find all Users with 'id': (0, 17) (found 1 results, but was
>   looking for 2)

Doing `.merge(:user_ids =>  [current_user.id])` instead results in the party only being created with the current user and removing all the selected users.

I've also tried moving the .merge to a function and calling it on new, but that doesn't seem to work either.

In my models a party `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` and likewise a user     `has_and_belongs_to_many :parties`

Any help appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
def party_params
  params.require(:party).permit(:length, :game_id, user_ids: []).tap do |p|
    p[:user_ids] << current_user.id
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly - I didn't know about .tap so that will be useful in future.